# How do I update joined data from MySQL programmatically?

Tags: qgis, python, mysql

I have a point vector layer (Sensores) in my QGIS project, I also have a MySQL database layer (SensoresDB) containing only data. I have joined these two layers in order to geographically reference my MySQL data and classify it.

[image]

My problem is the data in my vector layer (Sensores) doesn't update when the data in the MySQL layer (SensoresDB) does. That's ok, I don't need it to update in the exact moment it changes, but it would be nice if I could force it with code. I've tried using *layer.setCacheImage(None)* and *layer.triggerRepaint()* to no avail. Until now, the only way it does update is when I close the project and open it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might I suggest creating a **macro** which contains a function to rejoin both your layers. Using this method then allows you to run the function from the **Python console** whenever you want to update the vector layer.

You can do this by going to the toolbar:

`Project > Project Properties > Macros`

And then insert the following code:

```
shp = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( "Sensores" )[0]
mysql = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( "SensoresDB" )[0]

# Set JOIN properties by changing 'ID' to relevant field names
shpField='ID'
mysqlField='ID'
joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = mysql.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = mysqlField
joinObject.targetFieldName = shpField

def update():
    shp.removeJoin(mysql.id())
    shp.addJoin(joinObject)
    shp.triggerRepaint()
```

[image: Macro]

Make sure that you save the project and enable macros by going to the toolbar:

`Settings > General > Enable macros`

Now the next time you reload the project and you edit your MySQL layer, just type `update()` in the **Python console** and it should rejoin and update your vector layer accordingly.

Comment: Well, I'm developing a plugin for my university and, as I'm not gonna be the end user, it has to be automatic, so I didn't use a macro. I instead put the same code to rejoin both layers on a thread that runs every 5 minutes. It works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @JairNájeraSalaices - That's a cool idea! And most welcome =)